# mvvmcross navigation issue, getting exception: Could not find view for [ViewModelName]

Tags: c#, mvvmcross

I seem to be confused at how to make MvvmCross detect my ViewModels that are associated with views in Mono for Android. I tried to follow TwitterSearch in implementing the navigation but it just won't work.

```
RequestNavigate<LoginViewModel>();
```

here's my view:

```
[Activity(Label = "Login")]
public class LoginActivity : MvxBindingActivityView<LoginViewModel>
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        App.InitializeRestConnection(this);
    }

    protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LoginBindable);
    }

}
```

here's the exception:

```
I/ActivityManager(  307): Displayed com.desco.pendulum/pendulum.androidapp.SplashScreenActivity: +1s373ms (total +4s420ms)
I/Navigation( 8643):   0.50 Navigate to LoginViewModel with args
I/mono-stdout( 8643): Navigation:Diagnostic:  0.50 Navigate to LoginViewModel with args
I/MonoDroid( 8643): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Could not find view for dESCO.Mobile.ViewModels.LoginViewModel
I/MonoDroid( 8643): at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.MvxViewsContainer.GetViewType (System.Type) <0x001a4>
I/MonoDroid( 8643): at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewsContainer.GetIntentFor (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.MvxShowViewModelRequest) <0x00023>
I/MonoDroid( 8643): at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewPresenter.Show (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.MvxShowViewModelRequest) <0x00037>
I/MonoDroid( 8643): at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewDispatcher/<>c__DisplayClass1.<RequestNavigate>b__0 () <0x0002f>
I/MonoDroid( 8643): at Java.Lang.Thread/RunnableImplementor.Run () <0x0003f>
I/MonoDroid( 8643): at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (intptr,intptr) <0x00037>
I/MonoDroid( 8643): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.7060b187-418d-4bca-ad4f-8b9cae936501 (intptr,intptr) <0x0003b>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Just checking: when you say the navigation just won't work, are you saying that it won't work for you in TwitterSearch either?

Comment: Stuart, TwitterSearch works fine. I tried to follow it as a guide but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't see anything obviously wrong with your setup.

The default Droid framework setup looks for classes which implement IMvxAndroidView in the ExecutingAssembly using the logic in: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Platform/MvxBaseSetup.cs#L200

So I can't see any obvious reason why your LoginActivity View isn't being picked up.

One quick thing you could do is to add some debug code to your Setup.cs to see what views are being detected:

```
  protected override IDictionary<Type, Type> GetViewModelViewLookup()
  {
      var toReturn = base.GetViewModelViewLookup();
      MvxTrace.Trace("Tracing viewModels and views");
      foreach (var kvp in toReturn)
      {
          MvxTrace.Trace("Seen pair {0} : {1}", kvp.Key.Name, kvp.Value.Name);
      }
      return toReturn;
  }
```

If that shows the list is empty or missing your activity, then I'm afraid we'd need to step through the reflection logic to find out why it's not picking up your Activity.

---

In real desperation, you could also fake the results:

```
  protected override IDictionary<Type, Type> GetViewModelViewLookup()
  {
      return new Dictionary<Type,Type>() { { typeof(LoginViewModel), typeof(LoginActivity) } };
  }
```

But this probably isn't the right long-term solution for you

---

If this is caused by some kind of 'solution setup' difference - e.g. if you have somehow put your Setup.cs in a different project to your views - then it may be that somehow overriding the default convention will help you.

To achieve this, in you Setup.cs, override the code:

```
    public virtual Assembly ExecutableAssembly
    {
        get { return GetType().Assembly; }
    }

    protected override IDictionary<System.Type, System.Type> GetViewModelViewLookup()
    {
        return GetViewModelViewLookup(ExecutableAssembly, typeof (IMvxAndroidView));
    }
```

in the base setup class - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Platform/MvxBaseAndroidSetup.cs

This can be done either by overriding the ExecutingAssembly property (although this seems a bit wrong given it's name) or by overriding the GetViewModelViewLookup method. For example, if you wanted to look in several separate assemblies you could use:

```
    public List<Assembly> MyViewAssemblies { get; set; }

    protected override IDictionary<System.Type, System.Type> GetViewModelViewLookup()
    {
        var toReturn = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

        foreach (var assembly in MyViewAssemblies)
        {
            var contributions = base.GetViewModelViewLookup(assembly, typeof (IMvxAndroidView));
            foreach (var kvp in contributions)
            {
                toReturn[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value; 
            }
        }

        return toReturn;
    }
```

Comment: The only major difference is that in my case ViewModels are in the separate project from StartNavigation. Could that be an issue? Splashscreen comes up just fine because its a mainlauncher. Then StartNavigation kicks in and that's when the app is crashing.

Comment: I can't see why the StartNavigation location should matter. The Setup.cs location would matter though - as currently the convention does expect the Setup class to be in the same Assembly as the Views. I've added some code to the answer about how to use a custom set of assemblies for your Views.

Comment: Stuart, thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Turns out my Setup class was deriving from MvxSimpleAndroidBindingSetup. Once I changed that to MvxBaseAndroidBindingSetup, navigation started working.

Comment: Dead mvvmcross links.