# MvvmCross Not Loading Plugins in iOS 8

Tags: ios, plugins, mvvmcross

I'm working on an enterprise iOS app using MvvmCross 3.2.1 and iOS 8 (with updated profile 259) and it's throwing exception "Failed to resolve parameter for parameter factory of type ISQLiteConnectionFactory when creating MyDataService".

The same application works fine using MvvmCross 3.1.1 and iOS 7 and profile24.

It's appearing that the PlugIns aren't being loaded in time based on the application output.

Here's a snippet of the output from the version that works:

> 2014-09-25 09:30:36.453 MyApp[2665:70b] mvx: Diagnostic:   5.19
>   Setup: MvvmCross settings start 2014-09-25 09:30:36.453
>   MyApp[2665:70b] mvx: Diagnostic:   5.19 Setup: Singleton Cache
>   start 2014-09-25 09:30:36.454 MyApp[2665:70b] mvx: Diagnostic: 
>   5.19 Setup: Bootstrap actions 2014-09-25 09:30:36.466 MyApp[2665:70b] mvx: Diagnostic:   5.20 Setup:
>   StringToTypeParser start 2014-09-25 09:30:36.469
>   MyApp[2665:70b] mvx: Diagnostic:   5.21 Setup:
>   ViewModelFramework start 2014-09-25 09:30:36.470
>   MyApp[2665:70b] mvx: Diagnostic:   5.21 Setup:
>   PluginManagerFramework start 2014-09-25 09:30:36.475
>   MyApp[2665:70b] mvx: Diagnostic:   5.21 Ensuring Plugin is
>   loaded for Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.PluginLoader 2014-09-25
>   09:30:36.478 MyApp[2665:70b] mvx: Diagnostic:   5.22 Ensuring
>   Plugin is loaded for Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Network.PluginLoader
>   2014-09-25 09:30:36.479 MyApp[2665:70b] mvx: Diagnostic:   5.22
>   Ensuring Plugin is loaded for
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.PluginLoader 2014-09-25
>   09:30:36.480 MyApp[2665:70b] mvx: Diagnostic:   5.22 Ensuring
>   Plugin is loaded for
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite.PluginLoader 2014-09-25
>   09:30:36.481 MyApp[2665:70b] mvx: Diagnostic:   5.22 Ensuring
>   Plugin is loaded for Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger.PluginLoader
>   2014-09-25 09:30:36.482 MyApp[2665:70b] mvx: Diagnostic:   5.22
>   Ensuring Plugin is loaded for
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.ResourceLoader.PluginLoader 2014-09-25
>   09:30:36.483 MyApp[2665:70b] mvx: Diagnostic:   5.22 Ensuring
>   Plugin is loaded for
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.WebBrowser.PluginLoader 2014-09-25
>   09:30:36.484 MyApp[2665:70b] mvx: Diagnostic:   5.22 Setup: App
>   start

And here's the output for the iOS version that throws the exception:

> 2014-09-25 09:36:35.078 MyApp[2889:122068] mvx: Diagnostic:
>   6.69 Setup: MvvmCross settings start 2014-09-25 09:36:35.078 MyApp[2889:122068] mvx: Diagnostic:   6.69 Setup: Singleton
>   Cache start 2014-09-25 09:36:35.079 MyApp[2889:122068] mvx:
>   Diagnostic:   6.69 Setup: Bootstrap actions 2014-09-25 09:36:35.096
>   MyApp[2889:122068] mvx: Diagnostic:   6.71 Setup:
>   StringToTypeParser start 2014-09-25 09:36:35.098
>   MyApp[2889:122068] mvx: Diagnostic:   6.71 Setup: CommandHelper
>   start 2014-09-25 09:36:35.098 MyApp[2889:122068] mvx:
>   Diagnostic:   6.71 Setup: ViewModelFramework start 2014-09-25
>   09:36:35.099 MyApp[2889:122068] mvx: Diagnostic:   6.71 Setup:
>   PluginManagerFramework start 2014-09-25 09:36:35.101
>   MyApp[2889:122068] mvx: Diagnostic:   6.71 Setup: App start

With the missing "Ensure PlugIn loaded" statements, I'm thinking that the PlugIns aren't being loaded (I'm using File, Messenger, Visibility, Community Sqlite, Network, ResourceLoader and WebBrowser).

As part of my debugging process, I integrated my application directly with the MvvmCross source code, using project references rather than packages.  Not sure if that makes a difference but thought I should mention it.

Still relatively new to MvvmCross, and any thoughts on why the PlugIns aren't loaded or what I might be missing in the conversion to iOS 8 would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This sounds similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005309/mvvm-cross-resolve-imvxtouchviewcreator-fails-ios-8 - it sounds like this is some kind of Xamarin linker change for ios8 and that it only hits some projects - maybe ask Xamarin support for guidance?

Comment: Thanks for your input!  That was one of the issues I was working on to resolve that made me attempt to integrate MvvmCross.  However, that one is resolved now, so I  am in good shape.